# data:// url works on Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, firefox

My HTML page contains the following video tag:

```
<video id="video" src="data://video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAG..."></video>
```

The video tag contains a a base64 version of a 2MB mp4 clip of Big Buck Bunny (truncated in snippet to fit in post).

This loads perfectly fine on Firefox, but doesn't load at all on Chrome, and does not throw any errors to the console. Initially my thought was this error was due to some URL length constraint not met on Firefox but met on chrome, however , my page still does not work on Chrome with smaller source videos. Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Comment: Removing `//` might help, but I'm not sure, like `data:video/mp4;...`. But I really don't recommend you embed videos in a Base64 URL.

Comment: Hm, I thought that too, initially, but I tested it, and it works both ways for me. So maybe it's indeed a codec problem.

Comment: @CherryDT I think it would be best to stick to the [specification format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397)

Comment: I agree, I'm just saying that's likely not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out @code was correct.
My problem was that I messed up the formatting of the data URL by using 2 slashes `data://`, rather than the correct format of `data:`

```
data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAG...
```

The above finally works on **both browsers**.
Firefox accepts both formats — while Chrome is more strict about that rule. A bit annoying Chrome doesn't throw any error for it.